# return Null when i export (Texture) in GDScript

Tags: godot

I creating game about tank battle. I have already wrote script which be constructor for all tanks Node. Part of this script export tank's Texture and then make Node. this look like this:

```
export (Texture) var chassis_texture;

func _init():
    var chassis_collision = CollisionShape2D.new();
    var chassis_shape = RectangleShape2D.new();
    var chassis_sprite = Sprite.new();

    chassis_sprite.texture = chassis_texture;
    chassis_shape.extents = chassis_texture.get_size()
    chassis_collision.shape = chassis_shape;

    add_child(chassis_sprite);
```

So even if I specify the texture in the editor, chassis_texture equals Null
How fix this? thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2):

Godot calls the method `_init` just before setting the exported variables. *I went over the order in another answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66945513/how-to-make-multimesh-construction-script-for-godot/66947013#66947013).* Because of that, when `_init` runs, your exported variable is *still* `null`. The simplest solution is to move your code to `_ready`.