# A export value set in the editor shows its a zero in the code

Tags: godot

I have this beautiful script that is a resource that allows me to make mulitple units, in the script/resource I have it calculate the stats of the units damage, health etc, but I have the base stats set up as export values so i add them in the editor, but for what ever reason the script its self ignores the export values and thinks them as zeros but I know that some export values work because when i print say the base_hp it prints it correctly but when i try to print just hp its just 5, (it seems the added 5 at the end works, makes sense to me at least) but the ints dont remember unless I make it a function that calls them to return it correctly.

Here is the script, am I making a mistake somewhere this is the second time I actually tried using a resource but this can be annoying.

```
extends Resource
class_name Monster

export(Texture) var front_sprite
export(Texture) var back_sprite
export(String) var name
export(int) var level
# Gets the types and gives the monster a type
export(TypeData.types) var type_1 = TypeData.types.none
export(TypeData.types) var type_2 = TypeData.types.none
# Base stats the limit the amount of points a monster can get
export(int) var Base_hp
export(int) var Base_attack
export(int) var Base_special_attack
export(int) var Base_defence
export(int) var Base_special_defence
export(int) var Base_speed
# The avaliable moves the monster can use to attack or other actions
export(Array,Resource) var move_slot = [null,null,null,null]
# The monsters stats based on the level
var hp  = ((float(Base_hp * level) / 100.0) + 5.0)
var attack = ((float(Base_attack * level) / 100.0) + 5.0)
var special_attack = ((float(Base_special_attack * level) / 100.0) + 5.0)
var defence = ((float(Base_defence * level) / 100.0) + 5.0)
var special_defence = ((float(Base_special_defence * level) / 100.0) + 5.0)
var speed = ((float(Base_speed * level) / 100.0) + 5.0)
# So when the monster takes damage we can takeaway the hp
var current_hp = hp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This had eluded me in the past. However, by resourcing to `OS.get_ticks_usec()` I figured out the timing of these variables. *And updated that answer where I go over the steps: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66947013/402022). Except that is for nodes, not resources, but the first three steps are the same.*

So, when this runs:

```
var hp  = ((float(Base_hp * level) / 100.0) + 5.0)
```

Godot has not set the exported value of `Base_hp` yet. It has its default, which you didn't specify. You could give it a default value like this:

```
export(int) var Base_hp = default_value
```

---

My first intuition was to use `_init`, however that will also run before Godot sets the exported values. And there is no `_ready` on `Resource`, nor any convenient signal, or notification, or method to override.

Using `setget` to keep track of the exported variables getting initialized would be overkill and error prone.

That let us with simply making getter methods for these variables:

```
func get_hp(): return ((float(Base_hp * level) / 100.0) + 5.0)
```

Or with some extra work:

```
var hp setget , get_hp; func get_hp(): return ((float(Base_hp * level) / 100.0) + 5.0)
```

Which will at least let you treat it like a variable. Except it recomputes the value when you read it, and setting it is wasted effort.

Comment: Thanks Theraot I wanted it to be simply be hp = calculation but I tried using a function and that works and that's what I used before but I thought it was messy but it seems there isn't any other way,plus having it as a function might be a plus since level will change and I don't remember if variables update as they go, thanks for the insight, one last question should I go and report this as a bug on GitHub or is this intended?

Comment: Should I go a different route and instead of using a resource you a script that extends a custom script with values, at least that way I can edit the script without it being a resource/scene

Comment: @Dragon20C I don't think this is not a bug, but arguebly a missing feature. You could try writing a proposal at https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals (open an issue) - A Resource for this makes sense. Something you might consider is making the Resource be only exported variables that never change, let us call it "MonsterDescriptor" and then have a Node "Monster" that exports a Resource "MonsterDescriptor" and has all the rest of logic. See also [Resources](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/resources.htm).